# mkdirs returns false in some device

Tags: android, file, mkdirs

This code works for me but it is reported in fabric crashlytics not work on some devices and actually mkdirs retrun false I checked already the dir.exists() before .

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/Gahvare/");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("in downloadFileWithProgressBar directory not exist, path: " + dir.getPath() + "  absolut path is :" + dir.getAbsolutePath()));
                //  callback.onFailure(CONNECTION_ERROR);
            }
        }
```

[image: fabric report]

device list not work[image: device list not work]

Comment: post your exception

Comment: On Android 10 Devices Only?

Comment: On Android 10 .

Comment: This is a problem on Android 4 and 5.
 I have outlined the problematic devices in the image @Andrew blackapps

Answer (score 0):

Try below in application manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.appname" 
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.2">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i used this permissions  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in app manifest  @Shanmuka Chowdary